# What is mean of 'Undefined function 'tfest' for input arguments of type 'idfrd'.'

Tags: matlab

When I tried to get transfer function from the data, it always returns this information, my friend is able to get result with Matlab 2012 (mine is 2011b). my code is as follow:

```
load CP.dat
f=CP(:,1)
gain=CP(:,2)
phase=CP(:,3)
gainn=10.^(gain/20)
response=gainn.*exp(1i*phase)
w=f*2*pi
g=idfrd(response,w,0)
sys=tfest(g,3)
```

Comment: If you read the documentation of [`tfest`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/tfest.html) it requires time-domain data as the input.  You are trying to put in a transfer function object instead.

Comment: CP.dat is a bode plot data file, includes frequency, gain and phase information.

Answer (score 1):

The `tfest` function was introduced into the R2012a version of MATLAB. See the release notes of its [toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/release-notes.html); look at the R2012a *New feature* section.

Comment: I hope to get a 3 order formula from the curve CP.dat, can I do it in 2011b?